# How to remove protein contamination in plasmid isolation.

Tags: molecular-biology

I have already tried phenol chloroform extraction, isopropanol precipitation, did not work. It is giving high 280 reading.

Comment: Can you please give some more details on your protocols and probably also show some spectrum?

Comment: I used Resuspension(mixed with RNase) buffer,then vortexed and added lysis buffer,shaking and then neutralization buffer and centrifuged. Took the supernatant,added 100%ethanol and incubated for 1hour,centrifuged,took the pellet(huge pellet came,must be because of protein), 70% ethanol wash ,dried and resuspended in TE buffer.

Comment: i also did phenol chloroform step next time after collecting the Supernatant after neutralization, protein layer did not come much.